# Replace element in a list of objects retrieved as property / public field

Tags: c#, .net, list, reference

I'm trying to do a simple thing - replace an object in a list with another one, 'more up to date'. The problem is the actual list is not getting updated. List is defined and stored in my `DataProvider` class:

```
public class CountriesDataSet
{
    List<Country> b;
    private IXmlBinder xmlBinder;

    public CountriesDataSet()
    {            
        xmlBinder = new BasicXmlLoader();
        Countries = xmlBinder.Load();
    }

    public List<Country> Countries;        

    public void Save()
    {
        xmlBinder.Save(Countries);
    }
}
```

And the usage is in another class, lets call it controller, where I store instance of my `CountriesDataSet` class.

I'm trying to do the update there:

```
  var countries = countriesDataSet.Countries;

  Country country = countries.First(c => c.Id == id);

  if (country != null)
  {                    
      country = newCountry;
      countriesDataSet.Save();                    
  }
```

I can see that country is replaced by new instance of `newCountry`, but no update on the `countriesDataSet.Countries`, what am I doing wrong? What would be correct way of approaching this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the info of `country` with `newCountry`

exemple:

```
var countries = countriesDataSet.Countries;
Country country = countries.First(c => c.Id == id);
if (country != null)
{                    
 country.State = newCountry.State;
 country.Flag = NewCountry.Flag;
 ...
 countriesDataSet.Save();                    
}
```

Or like that
:

```
int index = listofelements.IndexOf(oldValue);
if(index != -1)
    listofelements[index] = newValue;
```

Comment: This seems kind of lame, as I would have to copy all the values of the class, isn't there any pattern to cover that for me?

Comment: Could you give any comment why updating on element by IndexOf is working and the First not?

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the "up-to-date" values instead of creating a new instance.

Also, `First()` throws an exception if no match is found, which you're apparently concerned with since you test for `null`. Use `FirstOrDefault` (or `SingleOrDefault` if you expect at most one match).

```
var countries = countriesDataSet.Countries;
Country country = countries.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

if (country != null)
{                    
    country.SomeProperty = newCountry.SomeProperty;
    country.SomethingElse = newCountry.SomethingElse;
    countriesDataSet.Save();                    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var countries = countriesDataSet.Countries;
var index = countries.FindIndex(c => c.Id == id));
if (index >= 0)
     countries[index] = newCountry;
countriesDataSet.Save();
```